# Mongodb get document that has max value for each subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have some data looking like this:

```
    {'Type':'A',
     'Attributes':[
            {'Date':'2021-10-02', 'Value':5},
            {'Date':'2021-09-30', 'Value':1},
            {'Date':'2021-09-25', 'Value':13}
       ]
     },
    {'Type':'B',
     'Attributes':[
            {'Date':'2021-10-01', 'Value':36},
            {'Date':'2021-09-15', 'Value':14},
            {'Date':'2021-09-10', 'Value':18}
       ]
     }
```

I would like to query for each document the document with the newest date. With the data above the desired result would be:

```
{'Type':'A', 'Date':'2021-10-02', 'Value':5}
{'Type':'B', 'Date':'2021-10-01', 'Value':36}
```

I managed to find some queries to find over all sub document only the global max. But I did not find the max for each document.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing date as string is generally considered as bad pratice. Suggest that you change your date field into date type. Fortunately for your case, you are using ISO date format so some effort could be saved.

You can do this in aggregation pipeline:

1. use `$max` to find out the max date
2. use `$filter` to filter the `Attributes` array to contains only the latest element
3. `$unwind` the array
4. `$project` to your expected output

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lVaMKhD0vex) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

This keeps 1 member from Attributes only, the one with the max date.
If you want to keep multiple ones use the @ray solution that keeps all members that have the max-date.

*mongoplayground can lose the order, of fields in a document,
if you see wrong result, test it on your driver, its bug of mongoplayground tool

Query1 (local-way)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-m1mul9ZF3c)

```js
aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "maxDateValue": {
        "$max": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$Attributes",
            "in": { "Date": "$$this.Date", "Value": "$$this.Value" },
           }
         }
       },
      "Type": 1
     }
   },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Date": "$maxDateValue.Date", 
      "Value": "$maxDateValue.Value"
    }
  }
])
```

Query2 (unwind-way)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gUJ_FKQzdMJ)

```js
aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": { "path": "$Attributes" }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Type",
      "maxDate": {
        "$max": {
          "Date": "$Attributes.Date", 
          "Value": "$Attributes.Value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Type": "$_id",
      "Date": "$maxDate.Date",
      "Value": "$maxDate.Value"
    }
  }
])
```